# Magnolia JCR-SQL2 order by Date

Tags: magnolia, jcr-sql2

In the JCR, I've noticed that dates are stored in the format `Feb 19, 2015 12:00:00 AM`. This means that when you try and order a query by a date, it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:pages] ORDER BY articlePublishedDate
```

Will return:

- `Apr 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM`
- `Dec 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM`
- `Feb 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM`

Is there any way to make the `ORDER BY` clause act as a integer? I've tried `CAST(articlePublishedDate AS LONG)` but it appears my content repository doesn't like it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up sorting in code, as it wasn't supported by my implementation of JCR.

Answer (score 0):

This is more issue of JCR than Magnolia , however, one may do the following for working this around.

```
SELECT p.* FROM [mgnl:page] AS p
WHERE p.[mgnl:lastModified] > CAST('2016-06-10T07:24:50.233Z' AS DATE)
```

I assume order by also should work the same way.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `articlePublishedDate` node property is of type `Date`, not `String`. For example, the following JCR2 query returned the results in the correct order when executed on the `website` repository:

```
select p.* from [mgnl:page] as p order by p.[jcr:created] desc
```